highlighting text not working in react-pdf-viewer
I have two div's.

To display the pdf content. Example: "Dummy PDF File".
To show the words from the pdf. Example: "Dummy PDF File".

My requirement is when I mouse over a word in the second  let's say "Dummy", then that word should be highlighted in the first  pdf content.
When I mouse over the text, am getting the correct text in the console, but "renderHighlights" function is not triggered and am not getting the text highlighted in the pdf.
Below is my code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Worker } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core';
import { Viewer } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core';
import { defaultLayoutPlugin } from '@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout';
import { highlightPlugin, Trigger } from '@react-pdf-viewer/highlight';
import '@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/styles/index.css';
import '@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout/lib/styles/index.css';
import '@react-pdf-viewer/highlight/lib/styles/index.css';

const BoundingBox = () => {
  const defaultLayoutPluginInstance = defaultLayoutPlugin();

  // Using Trigger.TextSelection to allow text selection to trigger highlighting
  const highlightPluginInstance = highlightPlugin({
    trigger: Trigger.TextSelection,
  });

  const [highlightedWord, setHighlightedWord] = useState('');

  // Function to return the highlight areas dynamically
  const renderHighlights = () => {
    console.log("renderHighlights called with:", highlightedWord); // Debug log
    if (!highlightedWord) return [];

    const highlightColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)'; // Yellow color for highlight

    // Define the highlight areas based on the highlighted word
    if (highlightedWord === 'Dummy') {
  return [{
    pageIndex: 0, // Change to the correct page index
    rects: [
      { x: 50, y: 100, width: 100, height: 20, color: highlightColor }, // Adjust coordinates
    ],
  }];
} else if (highlightedWord === 'PDF') {
  return [{
    pageIndex: 0,
    rects: [
      { x: 50, y: 130, width: 100, height: 20, color: highlightColor }, // Adjust coordinates
    ],
  }];
} else if (highlightedWord === 'File') {
  return [{
    pageIndex: 0,
    rects: [
      { x: 50, y: 160, width: 100, height: 20, color: highlightColor }, // Adjust coordinates
    ],
  }];
}
return [];
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '600px' }}>
      {/* Left container for PDF */}
      <div style={{ flex: 1, border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)', padding: '10px' }}>
        <Worker workerUrl={`https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.10.377/build/pdf.worker.min.js`}>
          <Viewer
            fileUrl="/files/sample.pdf"
            plugins={[
              defaultLayoutPluginInstance,
              highlightPluginInstance,
            ]}
             renderHighlights={renderHighlights} // Render highlight based on the state
          />
        </Worker>
      </div>

      {/* Right container for text */}
      <div style={{ flex: 1, padding: '10px', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <h2
          onMouseEnter={() => setHighlightedWord('Dummy')}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHighlightedWord('')}
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
        >
      Dummy
    </h2>
    <h2
      onMouseEnter={() => setHighlightedWord('PDF')}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHighlightedWord('')}
      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
    >
      PDF
    </h2>
    <h2
      onMouseEnter={() => setHighlightedWord('File')}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHighlightedWord('')}
      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
    >
      File
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
  );
};

 export default BoundingBox;

Need some valuable help.
